# how to hide the content of the div in css

Tags: html, css

I have this html code

```
<div id="mybox"> aaaaaaa </div>
```

and this is my css

```
#mybox{
   background-color:green;
}

#mybox:hover{
   background-color:red;
}
```

the question is how to hide the content of the div (aaaaaaa) when the mouse hover event by using css only and without changing the structure of the code
I think I should put some code under `#mybox:hover` but I don't know the code.

Comment: Semantically, you would really be best off by using a paragraph or other element within the div. A div is a structural element and not intended to directly hold text.

Comment: That's a hard semantic to hold to. Who is without sin in this matter?!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Without changing the markup or using JavaScript, you'd pretty much have to alter the text color as knut mentions, or set text-indent: -1000em;

IE6 will not read the :hover selector on anything other than an anchor element, so you will have to use something like [Dean Edwards' IE7](http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/).

Really though, you're better off putting the text in some kind of element (like `p` or `span` or `a`) and setting that to `display: none;` on hover.

Comment: thanks, text-indent: -1000em; works very well and I think I will use it, and about IE6 simply I don't support it because it will lead to very complicated code,Thanks

Comment: This is a very handy trick when you still want to display the element's border, which is handy for drag-and-drop functionality.  If there's no need to display anything, `visibility:hidden` is probably your best bet, since `display:none` will be distracting and will cause reflow.

Answer (score 16):

Here is the simplest way to do it with CSS3:

```
#mybox:hover {
  color: transparent;
}
```

regardless of the container color you can make the text color transparent on hover.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 12):

Hiding through CSS is achieved by using either the "visibility" or the "display" attributes. Though both achieve similar results, it's useful to know the differences.

If you only want to hide the element but retain the space occupied by it, you should use:

```
#mybox:hover {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

If you want to hide the element and remove the space occupied by it, so that other elements can take its space, then you should use:

```
#mybox:hover {
   display: none;
}
```

Also remember that IE6 and below do not respond to :hover for anything except A tags. In which case, you'll need some Javascript to change the classname:

```
document.getElementById('mybox').className = 'hide';
```

and define the "hide" class in CSS:

```
.hide { display: none; }
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem from the post. It will hide the entire element, including the background color. The question was how to hide the content of an element without also hiding its background, and these techniques will not work for that purpose.

Answer (score 8):

sounds silly but font-size:0; might just work. It did for me. And you can easily override this with the child element you need to show.

Comment: I'm using `:after` to replace the contents and this was the one that worked perfectly. +1+

Answer (score 4):

You could make the text color the same as the background color:

```
#mybox:hover
{
  background-color: red;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: this is a good trick however it will not help in my case because I want to use background image in my div, thanks

Comment: you can add a background image on hover too with background-image: url(...) no-repeat left top, for example

Comment: This will not help with accessibility and screen readers :(

Answer (score 3):

What about opacity

```
#mybox:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to hide in html/css using `display:none;`

*Example*

```
<div id="divSample" class="hideClass">hi..</div>
<style>
.hideClass
{display:none;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer but still, guess setting the color to transparent is the best option.

```
#mybox:hover{
background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it:
One way:

```
#mybox:hover {
   display:none;
}
```

Another way:

```
#mybox:hover {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

Or you could just do:

```
#mybox:hover {
   background:transparent;
   color:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#mybox:hover { display: none; }
#mybox:hover { visibility: hidden; }
#mybox:hover { background: none; }
#mybox:hover { color: green; }
```

though it should be noted that IE6 and below wont listen to the hover when it's not on an A tag. For that you have to incorporate JavaScript to add a class to the div during the hover.

Comment: Thanks, I am not planning to support IE6 at least at this stage of my project, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

```css
#mybox{
  background:green;  
}

#mybox:hover{
  color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="mybox">
  This text will disappear on hover  
</div>
```

This will hide text, but of course, it still contains the text, but it is a tricky way to hide the text (make in invisible), but it will work well

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be 7 years late but this could be achieved by using the below:

```
.your-block{
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}
```

This will keep the content on the page and won't occupy any space whereas display:none will completely hide the content.

Using the above code can be useful if you need to reference code in a div but don't need it to display.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.button {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        font-size: 0;
        background: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2224%22%20height%3D%2224%22%20viewBox%3D%221284%20207%2024%2024%22%3E%3Cg%20fill%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M1298.5%20222.9C1297.5%20223.6%201296.3%20224%201295%20224%201291.7%20224%201289%20221.3%201289%20218%201289%20214.7%201291.7%20212%201295%20212%201298.3%20212%201301%20214.7%201301%20218%201301%20219.3%201300.6%20220.5%201299.9%20221.5L1302.7%20224.2C1303%20224.6%201303.1%20225.3%201302.7%20225.7%201302.3%20226%201301.6%20226%201301.2%20225.7L1298.5%20222.9ZM1295%20222C1297.2%20222%201299%20220.2%201299%20218%201299%20215.8%201297.2%20214%201295%20214%201292.8%20214%201291%20215.8%201291%20218%201291%20220.2%201292.8%20222%201295%20222Z%22%20fill%3D%22%239299A6%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E") #f0f2f5 no-repeat 50%;
    }
```

```html
<button class="button">Поиск</button>
```